# We got a situation

Tags: meaning

I heard this sentence from a movie. What does this mean? Each word is not difficult but I can't guess the setence's  meaning.

> We got a situation.

Comment: It means "we have a problem".

Comment: I would expect _We've got a situation_

Comment: *Got* in the meaning of *have* or *have got* is attested in a dictionary: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/got_1.

Answer (score 6):

What no one seems to have mentioned is that *got* is a colloquial, down-register substitution for *have* or *have got* or even *have gotten*. In fact, it can substitute for any verb that means *to acquire*.

> We got a dog.

This can mean

> We have a dog.

You will hear this used informally all the time, but you would be well advised not to use it in academic or formal writing. If you're writing for the sports page, though, no problem.

Other meanings are:

> We acquired a dog.
>
> We purchased a dog.
>
> We were given a dog.

Used in this sense, *got* is the past tense of *get*, and the simple past is no problem in any kind of writing or speaking. Which brings us to the next point.

As far as "We got a problem" goes, the most likely interpretation is that *have* has been dropped from the sentence's syntax. It's this that makes it colloquial and down-register. To promote it a level in formality, you would say

> We've got a problem.

Note that using uncontracted *have* would be to make a more forceful statement:

> We have got a problem.

Whereas the former statement is merely a more or less uncolored declaration, the latter alerts the listener that the problem is serious.

Comment: Google has 203 "revisionist" citations for [*Houston, we got a problem,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Houston%2C+we+got+a+problem%22), but that's as against 8,240 for [*Houston, we **have** a problem*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Houston%2C+we+have+a+problem%22) (which I *assume* is the historically accurate version, otherwise I'd be somewhat concerned about the academic prowess of NASA astronauts! :)

Comment: Yes, I glanced at some those 203 citations and every one of them was someone's misquotation of the actual words. This sort of thing is to be expected where everyone with Facebook is a "publisher" ...

Comment: I've no objection *in principle* to usages like *I got no problem with this*, so long as we all understand it's colloquial / informal and *may* be seen as "substandard" in some contexts. But it's not always a bad thing when "famous words" get persistently misquoted - personally I've always preferred [*Badges? We don’t need no stinkin’ badges!*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqomZQMZQCQ). Original: *Badges? We ain’t got no badges. We don’t need no badges. I don’t have to show you any stinkin’ badges!* in Bogie's *Sierra Madre*, but they got it "right" in *Blazing Saddles* later! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: My personal *bête noire* is misquotation #3 in [this list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9626/is-there-a-term-that-means-oft-used-misquotation). Twain was simply a much better writer than that.

Comment: I didn't realise *that* one had been adjusted. I see now [the original context](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Mark_Twain) was in a fairly formal-looking letter: *James Ross Clemens, a cousin of mine, was seriously ill two or three weeks ago in London, but is well now. The report of my illness grew out of his illness; the report of my death was an exaggeration.* Where it probably wouldn't have been appropriate to use the deliberately quirky format I've come to know and love, since very likely he wasn't even *trying* to be witty / lighthearted in that context.

Comment: Twain was *always* witty, though seldom lighthearted. What I love about his "report of my death is an exaggeration" is its use of understatement to make a stronger statement of self-deprecating humor.

Comment: Ah well. I miss half the witticisms posted on ELU, so if you tell me he *was* being witty (but not lighthearted) in that letter, I must concede the point. But even if it *is* just a result of me being more familiar with the "misquote" version, I think it's slicker with pluralised ***reports*** and ***are greatly exaggerated*** rather than ***is an exaggeration***.

Comment: Slicker! By gad, ye're a heathen then!

Comment: The disagreement with Twain was just a warm-up fight. I'm now [taking issue with the Bard himself!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/352515/can-dummy-it-occur-as-possessive-its/352670?noredirect=1#comment818148_352670)

Answer (score 2):

> [situation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/situation)
>   : an important or sudden problem
>
> 5. **b** :  a critical, trying, or unusual state of affairs :  problem

Without further context, it likely means *we have a problem*.

Answer (score 2):

It means you have a problem. But not just any problem, but a very serious problem. If a customer comes to your shop complaining about something they bought, then you have a problem. If that customer carries a gun, then you have a situation.

So you may hear "we have a situation" quite regularly if you watch action movies. In real life, I haven't ever used "we have a situation" or heard it used.